# Onchange select with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value from this select form, with the onchange function:

```
<p for="session">Time:</p>
<select class="form-control" id="session" name="session" onchange="myfunctionTime(this.value)"> 
   <option selected="selected" value="12:00">12:00</option>
   <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

On the top of the file I have the ajax function which I can see it's working because inside the console(f12) I see like "Session 16:00" or "Session 12:00" etc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunctionTime(session)
 {
    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'book.php?id=<?php echo $film_id; ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {option : session},
        success: function() {
            console.log("Session "+session);
        }
    });
}
```

At the end I have the php code that give me the error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: session in **C:\xampp\htdocs....** on line **262**

```
function myfunctionTime(){
        $session = $_POST['option'];
    }
    echo $session;
```

Comment: `$session` is out of scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php You also never call the PHP function `myfunctionTime` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Change that lines of code to

```
    $session = $_POST['option'];
    echo $session;
```

Not a good way to do. But given your code, it works.

Comment: do you have any other code in book.php. check whether if you are using $session variable previously without defining it.

Comment: No sorry, I dont have another session variable in the code